# Possible to redirect to a page that uses standardSetController from another Visualforce page?

Tags: list-view, standardsetcontroller

Can a Visualforce page that uses a standardSetController be redirected to (with a list of records passed in) from anywhere other than a list view button?

Comment: Are you attempting to redirect in Apex, or JavaScript?

Comment: Either would fine. I have a Visualforce page where I want the users to be able to select from a list and then redirect to a Visualforce Page (from a managed package) that uses a Standard List Controller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't redirect in Apex, because redirects require PageReference, and PageReference doesn't support having a single query string key with multiple values. However, you can do this in JavaScript by constructing a URL that passes in multiple `ids` values:

```
/apex/pagename?ids=recordid1&ids=recordid2&ids=recordid3...
```

This was mentioned in a post from Skuid that documented the way to do it [on this page](https://community.skuid.com/skuid/topics/passing-selected-id-to-apex-class-using-standard-set-controller).

Answer (score 0):

You could go the route of cramming a bunch of Ids into a URL however, [browsers have a maximum URL size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) which could cause problems for you.

Ideally, I'd recommend combining the two VF pages into a single page. That's probably the best bet. Create a wizard-like experience where they take action on a virtual page before the contents are replaced with a second virtual page.

You could flag all of the records before the redirect and then re-query for those flagged records on the destination page.

You could try to pass in a query to the new page via a URL. This is not ideal as it opens a window for SOQL injection. Even if you escape your query before using it a savvy user could edit the query to get to records you may not want them to get to.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery) got me thinking. I have not tried anything crazy like this, but you could try to parse your records into a hidden form and then instead of manually redirecting the user you can submit the form via javascript and post the data to your new page. Then you could **try** to capture the data using `ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters()`. I have no idea if this works but you can bet that I'll be testing it when i get time and posting my results here.